# Multiple screen control with RPi4

Tags: hdmi, display, screen

I have a question regarding Raspberry Pi 4. Can I control 6 inch, 3 oled screens with Rpi 4?
I want to render all the screens differently, is that possible? Thanks in advance for your answers.

OLED 6 inch :

https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/6-Inch-Oled-Display-Oled-Display_62460089377.html?spm=a2700.7724857.topad_classic.d_image.21ce3d1eHnavFJ

Comment: We would need more detail on the screens to be able to answer this.

Comment: actually, i think for the screen i left the link in my question. I want to design a 360 degree screen using 2 or 3 of these screens.

Comment: "I want to design a 360 degree screen using 2 or 3 of these screens." so design it. If you have any questions about how to interface to the Pi ask a Question about that.

Comment: So let me ask, I want to get a single 360-degree screen using 3 screens. Will the rpi 4 hardware and software provide me with this? Can you say you can do it with 2 screens, not 3 screens?

Comment: ask the manufacturer if they have a multi-screen solution

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the product description, you need to use a MIPI DSI port per display. A Raspi 4 has only one of these ports. So without using an additional hardware extension, I would say: No that is impossible.

Perhaps the manufacturer has special interface hardware for combining some of these displays or you could use an Raspberry Compute Module which has two MIPI Ports.

I could also imagine, one can use a HDMI to MIPI DSI Bridge (not MIPI **C**SI) for one display and the internal DSI connector for another display. But I dont know if the standard raspian driver can handle a multi display solution in that configuration.